# SQL Server 2014 cannot connect to remote Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, connection, remote-access, remote-debugging

Before I get flagged, I will say that I have tried everything that I could find, but I still cannot connect:

- I have opened TCP Port (1433), Server is listening on ['any' < ipv4 > 1433].
- I have enable the server browser service
- I have enabled remote connections in my SQL server
- I have also assigned the TCP port to the TCP protocol for sqlexpress [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBitD.png)
- I also tried tried to debug the connection using the NETSTAT.exe and it says the TCP 1433 is listening.
- I have restarted the service several times when I try to connect from my local PC I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3RF9.png)

I can connect remotely to my server using IIS and url.

Question:
What can I do to debug the connection between the devices?

Comment: Please paste the error message as text into the question. Also did you mean to type restarted instead of retarded? They have really different meanings

Comment: When you say 'opened TCP port', did you open it up in the firewall?

Comment: When you check the log on the SQL server do you see a failed login for your SA account?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Yes i ment restarted :) lol, yes i have opened it in the firewall, i dont get a failed login in the logs

Comment: Try first locally, and then remotely to telnet to the IP on port 1433, eg `telnet 192.168.86.33 1433`.  If the console window goes blank, you have connected.  Otherwise you will get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people that are interested in the question.

I have fixed the issue, (by luck), so what I did I was playing around with the different kind of ports and I added a rule for range ports from

> 1430 to 1440

and that seemed to fix the problem.
[Check it out here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOM8t.png)

*Also for people that use Azure make sure to add a rule in the network security group.*

Thanks for the help

Comment: This solution seems flawed

Comment: @WhatsThePoint this allowed me to connect i will leave it at that now.

Comment: Are you not scared of the potential security risks involved with opening up extra ports?